# Replicating GETBIT() in Snowpark Python

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to replicate Snowflake's `GETBIT()` SQL function in Snowpark python. Effectively I want to call something like `df.filter(getbit(col("A"), 1) = 1)`. Alas, there's no `snowflake.snowpark.functions.getbit`.

I'm trying to go by way of casting my column as a binary string first, but getting weird behavior with the `as_binary` function:

```python
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col, as_binary
df = session.create_dataframe([1, 2, 3, 4]).to_df("a")
df.select(as_binary(col("a"))).show()
```

Returns me all `NULL`s:

```
----------------------
|"AS_BINARY(""A"")"  |
----------------------
|NULL                |
|NULL                |
|NULL                |
|NULL                |
----------------------
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Rather than referring to specific functionality in a different programming language, please use English to explain what the replacement code needs to do. See [How should we tag code translation questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265825) on Meta for details.

Comment: That said, `as_binary` is not going to be relevant here. The important thing to understand is that **there is no such thing as** a "binary number". Binary is a **way to represent** numbers. If the goal is to figure out what a particular bit would be in the binary representation of an integer, we do this by using *bitwise operators*, not by converting to a different type.

Comment: Does [Get n-th bit of an integer](/questions/9298865) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Snowflake, so I don't know if this answers your question or not.  Here's an answer that applies to Pandas Dataframe's and I would hope could be applied to your situation as well.

Defining a function in Python that tests a single bit can be done like this:

```
def is_bit_set(val, bit_index):
    return val & 1 << bit_index != 0
```

You can apply this to a dataframe using a lambda to test a specific bit in a specific column.  Here's an example that tests the `1` bit of the `a` column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4], columns=['a'])

df_is_bit_1_of_a_set = df['a'].apply(lambda v: is_bit_set(v, 1))
print(df_is_bit_1_of_a_set)
```

Result:

```
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

If you want to extract the value of a bit rather than testing it (you want 0 or 1 vs True or False), you can do this:

```
df_bit_1_of_a = df['a'].apply(lambda v: 1 if is_bit_set(v, 1) else 0)
print(df_bit_1_of_a)
```

Result:

```
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    0
Name: a, dtype: int64
```